# How do I upload apks to Crashlytics without running them first?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

Our CI server makes feature builds for us, which are custom versions of our app based off of whatever feature branch we're currently working on. We like having the apps on Fabric, because then it's easy for us to distribute them to the team and download them to test via the Fabric Beta app. The apks are uploaded using the gradle task `:app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug`.

However, this will fail if the app is new to Crashlytics; specifically if it has never been run before. The upload will fail with this error:

```
WARN - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the distribution. Project dev is inactive
:app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug'.
> Distribution upload failed.
```

One silly workaround is to make the CI server launch our app for a moment (say, in an emulator or physical device) before uploading it, so the app can run `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` and thus add the app to Crashlytics.

However, I'd like to avoid that and ideally just run a gradle task to add the app before the upload step, so that it can succeed. Is this possible?